# How can I find biggest number in a specific row of 2d array?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I need to find the biggest value of the specific row in the 2d array.

```
  static void BiggestValueOfKRow(Matrix matrica, int j, out int maxI)
             {
                int max = matrica.TakeValue(0,j);
                maxI = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < matrica.n; i++)
                {
                    if (matrica.TakeValue(i, j) > max)
                    {
                        max = matrica.TakeValue(i, j);
                        maxI = i;
                    }
                }
            }
```

I have tried other options before, but I still can not get it.
I should be able to choose number of the row and then int that row I have to find that biggest value

Comment: I recommend you use more descriptive identifiers than `j` and `i`. For example, the method is named `BiggestValueOfKRow` - so `j` should be renamed to `k` or `kthRowIndex` to be clear.

Comment: What does `matrica.n` refer to? Is it the width of the matrix or the total cell-count of the matrix? Or something else? (This is why descriptive names are important).

Comment: Is the matrix in column-major or row-major order?

Comment: What is the definition of `TakeValue`? Why are you using a custom matrix-class instead of a native 2D array or jagged-array?

Comment: The method is named `BiggestValue...` but its output parameter returns an index - in which case the method should be renamed to something like `GetIndexOfMaxValueOfKthRow`. Naming matters when both the index `i` and value `max` share the same type (`Int32`).

Comment: ...`matrica.n` What is `n`. Is that number of columns? Also, since you are using a custom `Matrix` class, this function might be better suited as a member function of that class.

Comment: Can you please add in the question what is your expected result and what is the actual result for some test data (and include test data in the question)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Matrix::TakeValue(a,b)` is column-major and `Matrix::n` is the absolute width of the matrix (i.e. an exclusive upper-bound, rather than an inclusive upper-bound), here is how I would do it, using `MaxBy`:

```
// Requires C# 7.3 for the use of value-tuples:

static (Int32 columnIndex, Int32 value) GetRowMax( Matrix m, int rowIndex )
{
    if( m == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof(m) );

    return Enumerable
        .Range( 0, m.n )
        .Select( colIdx => ( columnIndex: colIdx, value: m.TakeValue( colIdx, rowIndex ) ) )
        .MaxBy( t => t.value );
}
```

Note that `MaxBy` is not a part of normal Linq (grrr) however it is included in almost every decent Linq extension library, such as Jon Skeet's MoreLINQ.

An implementation of `MaxBy` is provided below:

```
// Rather than defining `MaxBy` yourself, you can also use MoreLINQ from NuGet.

static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static T MaxBy<T,TValue>( this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T,TValue> selector )
        where TValue : IComparable<TValue>
    {
        if( source == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof(source) );
        if( selector == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof(selector) );

        TValue max = default(TValue);
        foreach( T item in source )
        {
            if( item != null && item.CompareTo( max ) > 0 )
            {
                max = item;
            }
        }

        return max;
    }
}
```